# extended ASCII Conversion in Java

Tags: java

My code which is simply casting the ascii character to get decimal value and it is working properly. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
char character = 'A';
int intChar = (int) character;
System.out.println("Decimal Value is " + intChar);
}
```

Which returns me correct output as below:
Decimal Value is 65

Above code is working fine when characters range is from 0 to 127 (US-ASCII). But when I am trying to get the decimal value for extended ascii characters it 
returns me wrong decimal number. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
char character = 'Š';
int intChar = (int) character;
System.out.println("Decimal Value is " + intChar);
}
```

Which returns me incorrect output as below:
Decimal Value is 352

Instead it should return 138 as decimal value. 352 is the Unicode value for character 'Š' but I am expecting 138 which is correct value. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Decimal value of this Š 352

Comment: Java uses Unicode by default, so 0x0160 (decimal 352) is the code I'd expect for Š (character U+0160). You're asking for conversion to some other encoding; please say which encoding you want. Some Windows code page, perhaps?

Comment: Looks like Windows CP 1252

Comment: Isnt a char implicitely casted?

Comment: Could be Windows code page [1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), [1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), or [1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254).